# I have a iiyama ProLite E2473HS and whenever I try to run Windows 8.1 I get an error on my monitor saying Out Of Range what can i do to fix this?

Tags: display

So what can I do to fix it? It's really annoying and I really need some help

So I woke up this morning excited to use my new pc build, but when I booted it up all I could see was Out Of Range on my monitor, I had a few graphics issues the day before which I just thought was the drivers since I had not installed them yet I installed the drivers coupled with Windows updates. I have tried re-installing Windows 8.1 but nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that Windows has set your graphics adapter to a recommended resolution that is too high for your monitor. This often occurs when the monitor hasn't been "plug & play" installed by Windows so that Windows itself can know the maximum resolution your screen is capable of - what would the point be in Windows offering higher resolutions than the monitor can handle? It will produce precisely the symptoms you describe.

To get round this, Windows employs an advanced startup option called **VGA Mode**.

As your computer is technically booting up normally we need to force Windows to start into **Safe Mode**. Windows 8, however, does not have a **Safe Mode**, it has **Advanced startup options**:

[image]

For a normally functioning Windows install this screen shouldn't appear and can only be entered through Windows. But what happens if you can't see the screen? We need to force Windows to display these options...

1. **Boot your computer** (wait a couple of minutes until it completely boots)
2. **Press and hold the power button** to forcibly power off the computer. You may have to do this a couple of times (I think it's 3 times)
3. At some point you should be taken to the above page where you should click `Startup Settings`
4. Click `Enable low-resolution video mode` - your computer will reboot normally but the graphics adapter should be forced into (I think) 800x600 resolution so you can install the monitor drivers or set your own resolution that you know your screen is capable of.

Comment: It happened again, it seems to only happen when I am trying to install drivers for my XFX R7770 with AMD auto-detect, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have access to another computer on the network? I've found that sometimes you can see the screen if you "remote desktop" to the machine (you may need to configure this before installing the drivers (or follow above steps to get VGA mode again)) and then you can try and set a suitable resolution to restore operation?

Comment: No I don't, but I have sorted it now. You have been a great help.