# "out of range!" error message after installing windows 10

Tags: windows-8, display, windows-10

My monitor is `iiyama prolite e2208hds` and whenever I turn my computer on, what I get is a black screen. Judging by the sound of the workstation, it boots up properly but it doesn't display any image (eg windows loader) two days ago I noticed that if I wait long enough I get the message mentioned in the topic of this question. I found this topic: [I have a iiyama ProLite E2473HS and whenever I try to run Windows 8.1 I get an error on my monitor saying Out Of Range what can i do to fix this?](https://superuser.com/questions/835269/i-have-a-iiyama-prolite-e2473hs-and-whenever-i-try-to-run-windows-8-1-i-get-an-e) however taking the steps @BigChris suggested didn't solve the issue. I mean - there are no specific drivers for my display, so I don't know what to do apart from installing win8.1 . Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm also not seeing the usual images that are shown during computer startup - like the logo of my motherboard manufacturer etc...

Comment: You mean "Out of range" error? If so please [edit] your question and fix the title which says "out of error" (which doesn't make any sense).

Comment: If you're not seeing the BIOS text/images, then it's porbably not software (Windows/drivers) that's the problem.  Ensure your video cable is properly/fully plugged in. Try another video cable. Try you monitor on another, known-good computer.  Try a different, known-good monitor on your computer.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yeah, it would be a big problem - I don't have any other pc or monitor, but I tried another video cable (borrowed from my company) and it was the same. Isn't there any diagnostic tool that I could run?

Comment: How would you expect a software diagnostic tool to detect a dead monitor? :)   The 'diagnostic tool' for determining if a monitor is dead or if it's a system problem, is to plug it into another working system.

Comment: Haha, point taken, but I was thinking about a diagnostic tool that would tell me if it's windows problem (since it all started after upgrade 8.1 -> 10)

Comment: 1) It's possible that you aren't seeing the BIOS images because they go by too quickly. I suggest that as you switch on the computer, you keep pressing the Del key repeatedly for, say, 20 seconds or until something appears on the screen - this is likely to make the computer enter the BIOS, whereupon you will know that the monitor is working. You can press the F10 key and answer `N` to exit the BIOS safely.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's a good suggestion. I'll try it next time, because for some reason now when I restart my computer everything is ok -.-

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch In that case, it could be that Windows 10 needed to update its video card driver. Do you happen to know if it has an Nvidia display card?

Comment: Yes, its NVidia 760GTX, but I doubt that windows updated the driver after I created this question. It's a normal behavior since the trouble started - on the first run my screen is all black, and on any subsequent run (like when I reboot the machine NOT USING reset button) it works ok. When the clock hits 11pm, I turn off my computer and I hit bed, then when I get up in the morning and try to run my machine it's all over again.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch Is there anything relevant in the Windows event logs? Are you using a custom resolution/refresh rate? If you wait for Windows to finish booting and then unplug the monitor lead for a few seconds does that jog it into working (the computer should re-read the monitor's parameters)? Is the monitor correctly identified in the Nvidia control panel?